Proof regarding partial derivatives and differentiability
I'm having a trouble in understanding the proof of Theorem 8 from Pugh's Real Mathematical Analysis 2nd Edition (p. 284).
On the 5th line from the bottom where use has been made of the chain rule and mean value theorem, I don't understand why the last term doesn't end with a $v_je_j$ instead of just $v_j$:
$$
f_i(p_j) − f_i(p_{j−1}) = g(1) − g(0) = g'(t_{ij}) = \frac{\partial f_i(p_{ij})}{\partial x_j} v_j.\label{1}\tag{1}
$$
The reason I think the $e_j$ is missing is based on the following.
The proof states:

$$
\sigma_j(t) = p_{j−1} + tv_je_j, \quad0 ≤ t ≤ 1
$$
By the one-dimensional chain rule and mean value theorem applied to the differentiable real-valued function $g(t) = f_i \circ \sigma_j(t)$ of one variable, there exists $t_{ij} ∈ (0, 1)$ such that
$$
f_i(p_j) − f_i(p_{j−1}) = g(1) − g(0) = g'(t_{ij}) = \frac{\partial f_i(p_{ij})}{\partial x_j} v_j
$$
where $p_{ij} = \sigma_j(t_{ij})$.

So, in order to get $g'(t_{ij})$ we apply the chain rule which results in the term $\dfrac{\partial f_i(p_{ij})}{\partial x_j}$ multiplied by the derivative of $\sigma_j(t_{ij})$.
I see that the derivative of the function $\sigma_j(t) = p_{j−1} + tv_je_j$ with respect to $t$ is $v_je_j$ so we end up with the following expression:
$$
g^\prime(t_{ij})=\frac{\partial f_i(p_{ij})}{\partial x_j}v_je_j
$$
whereas the book does not show the $e_j$. If someone is able to correct my  reasoning, that would be great.
My understanding is as follows:

$f_i$ takes in a vector and spit out a scalar,
$v$ is a vector,
$v_j$ is a scalar $e_j$ is a basis vector
$σ_j(t)$ takes in a scalar and spits out a vector
$\frac{\partial f_i(p_{ij})}{\partial x_j}$ is a scalar
$p_{ij} = σ_j(t_{ij})$ is a vector
$p$ is a vector

Hence, the LHS of \eqref{1}, i.e. $f_i(p_j) − f_i(p_{j−1})$ is a scalar, so the RHS needs to be the same way, but if  the $e_j$ is present I think that would make the RHS term, i.e.
$$
\frac{\partial f_i(p_{ij})}{\partial x_j} v_je_j,
$$
a vector which won't work.
Looking for clarification on where I'm messing up.
And while I'm here, the next bits of the proof introduce $R_i(v)$, seeking clarification of whether this is a scalar, seems it should be.

Thanks again @TedShifrin, still fuzzy for me. Do you have a reference with an example that demonstrates the rule you're talking about in the context of the chain rule?
The following may be moot given further understanding on my part, but if I look at the chain rule in general as: $c'(x) = a'(b(x))b'(x)$ the bit $a'(b(x))$ is covered by the term $\frac{\partial f_i(p_{ij}))}{\partial x_j}$ = $\frac{\partial f_i(\sigma_j(t_{ij}))}{\partial x_j}$ which Pugh does not parse further. Hence, the $v_j$ must come about from $b'(x)$ which I don't see coming about from your commment as $b(x)$ is $σ_j(t_{ij})$ and this takes in a scalar and spits out a vector whereas your comment refers to a differentiable function that takes in a vector and spits out a scalar.

It is not clear why you would like to add $e_j$. As for your final sentence, how could we guess what $R_i(v)$ denotes? We are not supposed to hold this book. Anyway, better only one question per post.

If you apply the derivative of. $f_i$ (which is a linear map) to the vector $e_j$ you get the partial derivative $\partial f_i/\partial x_j$.

Have added a few more details to clarify.

@TedShifrin, apologies, I don't follow your comment. Can you be explicit around the derivation?

What I said in words is that if $f\colon\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R$ is differentiable, then $Df(p)(ce_j) = c\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}(p)$. Pugh's applying that rule, together with the chain rule.

Thanks again @TedShifrin and sincere apologies for being a pain on this. I've added my additional query at the end of the question as it was too long to post as a comment here.

I am going to post an answer at this point, but I have to say I'm fond of my own text Multivariable Mathematics: Linear Algebra, Multivariable Calculus, and Manifolds; you might also find some of the YouTube lectures based on this text (linked in my profile) helpful.

I think you are a bit too preoccupied with the partial derivatives. Let's look at the set-up. We are looking at $g=f_i\circ\sigma_j$, with $f_i\colon\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R$ and $\sigma_j\colon\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$. The chain rule tells us that
$$g'(t) = (Df_i)_{\sigma_j(t)}\sigma_j'(t).$$
To make things less cumbersome, I'm going to drop the $i$ and $j$ and just write $g=f\circ\sigma$. Then
$$Df_p = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}(p) & \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2}(p) & \cdots & \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n}(p)\end{bmatrix}$$
and
$$\sigma'(t)=v_je_j=\begin{bmatrix} 0\\ \vdots\\ 0 \\v_j\\ 0 \\\vdots\\0\end{bmatrix}\begin{matrix} \\\\\leftarrow j^{\text th} \text{ position} \\\\\\\end{matrix} $$
as in the text. Multiplying the row vector $Df_{\sigma(t)}$ by the column vector $\sigma'(t)$ (which has a nonzero entry only in the $j$th position) gives
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}(\sigma(t))v_j.$$
Also, let me caution you to be careful to write $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}(p)$, not $\dfrac{\partial f(p)}{\partial x_j}$. As with single variable calculus, we want $f'(c) = \dfrac{df}{dx}(c)$, not $\dfrac{df(c)}{dx}$, which is $0$.

Thank you @TedShifrin for your time and patience.
